# If $\sqrt{2}\cdot \cos A = \cos B-\cos^3 B$ and $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sin A = \sin B-\sin^3 B$, determine $\sin(A-B)$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sqrt{2}\cdot \cos A = \cos B-\cos^3 B$ and $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sin A = \sin B-\sin^3 B$, determine $\sin(A-B)$

My Try: $\sqrt{2}\cdot (\cos A-\sin A) = (\cos B-\sin B)-(\cos B-\sin B)\cdot(1+\sin B\cdot \cos B)$

After then, how can I calculate it? Thanks

Comment: Try expressing $\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(A)\sin(B)$ entirely in terms of $\sin(B)$ and $\cos(B)$.

Comment: May help to note that $sqrt{2} \cdot \cos A = \cos B - \cos^3 B = \cos B (1 - \cos^2 B) = \cos B \sin^2 B$ and similar for transforming $\sin A$. Now plug this into the hint from @DilipSarwate.

Comment: Yeah, previous two hints pretty much solve the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for Giving me a hint.